# Google Cloud Functions Add values to a map in firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This is my code to add values to a map in firestore. At the moment the map gets overwritten everytime

```
exports.addTrainingtoList = functions.firestore
    .document('/users/{uid}/trainings/{trainings}')
    .onCreate((change, context) => {
        const doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.params.uid).collection('user').doc('trainings');
        const trainingsID = change.data().trainingsID;
        const trainingsName = change.data().training;
        const trainingsTimestamp = change.data().timestamp;

        doc.update({
            Trainings: {
                ...doc.Trainings,
                [trainingsID]: {
                    'trainingsName': trainingsName,
                    'trainingsDate': trainingsTimestamp,
                },
            },
        })

    });
```

This is my updated code after Franks answer:

```
    exports.addTrainingtoList = functions.firestore
        .document('/users/{uid}/trainings/{trainings}')
        .onCreate((change, context) => {
            const doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.params.uid).collection('user').doc('trainings');
            const trainingsID = change.data().trainingsID;
            const trainingsName = change.data().training;
            const trainingsTimestamp = change.data().timestamp;
    
            const nameField = trainingsID + ".trainingsName";
            const timestampField = trainingsID + ".trainingsDate";
            doc.update({
               Trainings: {
                    ...doc.Trainings,
                    [nameField]: trainingsName,
                    [timestampField]: trainingsTimestamp,
                   },
              })
    
        });
```

Currently the map is overwritten.

Here u can see what I get:

[image]

Here u can see what I want to have.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally with Franks help I found a solution for my problem.

```
exports.addTrainingtoList = functions.firestore
.document('/users/{uid}/trainings/{trainings}')
.onCreate((change, context) => {
    const doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.params.uid).collection('user').doc('trainings');
    const trainingsID = change.data().trainingsID;
    const trainingsName = change.data().training;
    const trainingsTimestamp = change.data().timestamp;

    const nameField = `trainings.${trainingsID}.trainingsName`;
    const dateField = `trainings.${trainingsID}.trainingsDate`;

    doc.update({

        [nameField]: trainingsName,
        [dateField]: trainingsTimestamp,
    })

});
```

This is the result:

[image]

If you finally want to delete values out of the map you can use:

```
exports.delTrainingtoList = functions.firestore
.document('/users/{uid}/trainings/{trainings}')
.onDelete((change, context) => {
    const doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.params.uid).collection('user').doc('trainings');
    const trainingsID = change.data().trainingsID;
    const trainingsName = change.data().training;
    const trainingsTimestamp = change.data().timestamp;

    const trainingsField = `trainings.${trainingsID}`;


    doc.update({

        [trainingsField]: FieldValue.delete(),
    })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

To [add nested fields in an object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) use dot notation like this:

```
const nameField = trainingsID + ".trainingsName";
const timestampField = trainingsID + ".trainingsDate";
doc.update({
    Trainings: {
        ...doc.Trainings,
        [nameField]: trainingsName,
        [timestampField]: trainingsTimestamp,
    },
})
```

---

Since you updated your question to show what you want to get, that can be accomplished with:

```
const trainingsID = change.data().trainingsID + Date.now();
```

And then your original code to update the document.

Comment: Hey Frank, thank u so much for ur answer. I have updated my post. It would be awesome, if u can give it a look.

Comment: Can you please revert your edit, and show the updated code as an **addition**? Right now my answer makes no sense anymore, and it's important to keep everything aligned for future visitors. I've updated my answer to show how to add a new map in the meantime.

Comment: I have updated my post. I think it should be understandable now. Furthermore I have updated my code with your new answer. change.data().trainings gets my trainingsID(training1635231834392037) because I store it in the document. So I think dont need Date.now(). I have tried to use ur code, just to look, if my map gets overwritten or if it adds the value. In combination of your code for trainingsID and my old code, the map still gets overwritten.